# What is this community forum all about?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to get any help here at all? I really need some assistance and I can see that so many questions here stay unanswered.

Comment: You only have one question here. You joined two days ago. There are a great number of examples of highly voted questions and answers. Coming at this topic from such a cynical basis from the outset seems unlikely to be fruitful in your purported search for help. You get out of the community what you put into it, and that includes an investment in understanding the expectations, formatting, and so forth to put your questions in the best place for volunteers to be able to answer them for the simple reward of internet points.

Comment: We should not deal with this kind of negativity. Just delete these posts and do not give them room.

Answer (score 10):

This is question that would be better suited for https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/ (being that it's about the site rather than Salesforce), but you need 5 reputation points to participate there.

In a nutshell though, this is a community focused on making a public repository of knowledge about the Salesforce platform and ecosystem. It's entirely volunteer-based (though there are some Salesforce employees floating around here). Nobody's getting paid to answer questions here, we're just volunteering our time, experience, and knowledge.

Another general goal of this site that I toss around is that we're not a service that writes code for free; rather, we're here to help people overcome very narrow and specific issues to help them become better programmers or admins.

The big parts of getting help from this community are:

- showing us what you've tried so far
- telling us what research you've done
- pointing to one very specific thing you're stuck on (I'm getting error x, I have this visualforce controller but the save button doesn't save the record, etc...)
- providing plenty of details (we can't log in to your org, and aren't mind readers. We only have the information you provide to us)

The easier you make it to understand your problem, the more likely it is you'll get a good answer.

I wanna say that the answer rate here is something like 73%. Many questions *do get answered*, some don't. Sometimes it's people asking us to do their work for free, other times, it's just because there's nobody around with the right knowledge to solve a particular problem.

Comment: Other reasons for questions not being answered include a failure to express the question with enough detail, a lack of context for the question, failure to show any effort in resolving the issue, asking questions that don't belong in this community etc.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! I've migrated your question to the Meta site, where questions about this forum are on topic. Our main site is reserved for questions about Salesforce implementation.

So far, I see that you've asked one question on our site, just yesterday. Please keep in mind that our community is 100% volunteers: we don't guarantee an answer on any timeline at all, but especially for more complex issues or less-common parts of the Salesforce product line, it may take a while before someone comes along with the right expertise and the spare time to provide a great answer. Also bear in mind that it's now the weekend, so activity is quite a bit lower.

---

If you'd like to improve your odds of getting a great answer quickly, your best course is to edit your post to bring it closer and closer to the standards that our site has established. You can learn about those standards by reading our Help Center, especially the pages [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You can also learn, of course, just by reading questions and answers that the community has upvoted to indicate they provide a lot of value.

Looking at [your post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334107/prm-reseller-orders-not-visible), I have some suggestions as to how you can improve the post to raise your odds of finding an answer.

1. One question per post. Your question currently includes at least two distinct issues, although they're both related to visibility. You'd need, in my opinion, to either go big - talk us through an architecture problem at the top level that you need to solve - or go narrow - focus on one of these two individual problems. Either way, be specific and detailed.
2. Not enough specifics. Both of the problems you're asking about are currently described at the level of a scenario or generic business requirement. We need to know *what you've done*: what specific implementation work has been achieved, and how is it not behaving as desired? For example,

> The direct sales manager has no visibility on what is being done towards customers, collaboration between sales reps is poor resulting in double work or confusion. - my solution would the Territory field management feature, is that correct?

doesn't give the community much to go on. Who is the Sales Manager? Is this a role, a profile, a user? What is the relationship between the sales manager and the sales reps in terms of hierarchy? What objects are involved? What is the current sharing configuration? There could be *many* valid responses to this prompt. By being specific, you can help identify the right one.

Lastly, I'll note: this feels rather like an interview or examination challenge. The community often does not receive those types of questions well, both because they are difficult to fit into our format effectively and because it's best for candidates to answer those questions based on their own knowledge. If this is such a question, it's best to present it in terms of your knowledge and your effort to understand, not a scenario you've been given.